# Select Certain Fields in JPA Query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following query with all of these join/fetches:

```
public interface InitiativeRepository extends JpaRepository<Initiative, Long> {
    @Query("select distinct i from Initiative i " +
            "left join fetch i.theme t " +
            "left join fetch t.themeQuestions tq " +
            "left join fetch tq.initiativeProfileQuestion ipq " +
            "left join fetch ipq.answers " +
            "left join fetch ipq.answerLogs al " +
            "where al.revision = i.revision " +
            "order by ipq.question asc")
    public List<Initiative> getThemeAndQuestionsAndAnswerLogs();
}
```

Because I'm doing so many joins, obviously hibernate is fetching all attributes of each object. For example, *left join fetch i.theme t* fetches all attributes of theme. What if I only want to fetch the theme name and themeQuestions attribute within the theme object (I don't want any unnecessary ones)?

I'm not sure if this is doable through only an annotated query. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: For a start, if you are just needing the `al` (answer logs) for the where clause condition, then you only need the `fetch` on the `i.theme` and `t.themeQuestions`. Don't `join fetch` anything that you don't need to return. The only way I know to return just selected columns/fields is to select the fields specifically as a list of columns and then build up the objects from the result set you get back.

Comment: Well, I'd like to fetch all of the objects listed. It's just- in the theme object itself, there are many attributes that are unnecessary for this query that would just take up unnecessary memory- especially when I'm expecting ~40,000 rows returned.

Comment: If you are getting all those other objects, then I don't think you will get much gain. You could split your `Theme` class so you have a one-to-one related Entity called `ThemeDetails`, say, and just don't get that object. That way `Theme` could just have the name and the list of `ThemeQuestions`.